# MS Lightswitch add parameter for screen form 'screen navigation / menu'

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need two screen navigation items (i.e. 2 menu items) pointing to same screen, but with different parameters. Is it possible or not, how to do it. I am using silver-light client.

My final goal is to use one screen for two jobs, which are 95% similar, but for some reason we need to have separate screens. But I don't want to create a separate screen, I want to use the same screen for both jobs with little tweaks.

Comment: What technology are your menu items?

Comment: Lightswitch has its own navigation menu based on silverlight.

Comment: What does a menu item code / xaml look like?

Comment: @Martin it does not provide any xaml, thats the problem. It creates the menu on its own. We can only provide screen with its name in the given UI.

Comment: have you got a printscreen of what you mean? just to make sure i understand

Comment: @Crezzer7 sorry not get your point. Do you want 'Scree Navigation Designer's print screen ?

Comment: Here is the screen shot: https://pubbpq-sn3302.files.1drv.com/y3p1zEmfsARe-0BVftX7WR9lgCxv2kz63w4Hl6E9WzRa_l5Ph2sn3Y-LIoyVFDvWH5ykzkuqMDtjw-T4y-ZFzl33J0kkF06m1RnZr6VP9o4llJ8xkoImzH4t1tsuj7EX5RnC_zjeH1W_xwXZUdGG4oqNwK9Rd75OC3_CUbbeQ1i6A8/Scree+Navigation.PNG

Comment: that url doesnt return anything...

Comment: Updated link: http://i63.tinypic.com/29ql9au.png